# arrays of references throwing errors related to scanner

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, reference, error-handling

Here's the code in question:

```
 public class GradeBookRunner
 {
 public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    out.println("Welcome to the Class Stats program!");
    int num = 1;
    int count = 0;
    String stuGrades = "";
    String stuName = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("What is the name of this class? ");
    String clsName = keyboard.nextLine();
    out.println("\n");
    out.print("How many students are in this class? ");
    int clsNum = keyboard.nextInt();
    Class CSAB = new Class(clsName, clsNum);
    out.println("\n");
    out.print("Enter the name of student 1 : ");
    stuName = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.next();
    out.print("Enter the grades for " + stuName + "\nUse the format x - grades ( 2 - 100 100) : ");
    //count = keyboard.nextInt();
    //keyboard.next();
    //for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    //{
        stuGrades += keyboard.nextLine() + " ";
    //}

    Student add = new Student(stuName,stuGrades);
    CSAB.addStudent(num, add);
    stuGrades = "";
    num++;
    out.println();
```

The code for the classes that this utilizes can be found at the following links:

Grades.java: http://pastebin.com/ahYRS2WD

Student.java: http://pastebin.com/EBF4BBCb

Class.java: http://pastebin.com/A1C9fCL1

My issue happens after I run the code and give input for the class name, class size, student name, those are all fine, it's this next bit that throws me an error, when I input the grades for the student such as `3 - 70.2 65.3 45.1`

**EDIT**
Here's the error I'm getting:

Welcome to the Class Stats program!
What is the name of this class? ap

How many students are in this class? 1

Enter the name of student 1 : hardly

Enter the grades for hardly

Use the format x - grades ( 2 - 100 100) : Exception in thread "main"

java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at lab19b.Grades.setGrades(Grades.java:31)

at lab19b.Grades.<init>(Grades.java:25)

at lab19b.Student.<init>(Student.java:27)

at lab19b.GradeBookRunner.main(GradeBookRunner.java:42)
```

**EDIT2**

I'm now thinking the issue is that I need `stuGrades` to read in the entire line such as `3 - 70.2 65.3 45.1` but I can't figure out which scanner statement I need to put the keyboard input to a string

**EDIT3**

Here's my evidence of a properly working `grades.java`:

```
package lab19b;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;

 public class GradesTester
 {
public static void main( String args[] )
 {
    Grades test = new Grades("5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88");
    out.println(test);
    out.println("sum = " + test.getSum());  
    out.println("num grades = " + test.getNumGrades());                                         
    out.println("low grade = " + test.getLowGrade());       
    out.println("high grade = " + test.getHighGrade()+ "\n\n");

    test.setGrades("9 - 10 70 90 92.5 85 95.5 77.5 88 100.0");
    out.println(test);
    out.println("sum = " + test.getSum());  
    out.println("num grades = " + test.getNumGrades());                                         
    out.println("low grade = " + test.getLowGrade());       
    out.println("high grade = " + test.getHighGrade());
```

with an output like this:
90.0 85.0 95.5 77.5 88.0

sum = 436.0

num grades = 5

low grade = 77.5

high grade = 95.5

10.0 70.0 90.0 92.5 85.0 95.5 77.5 88.0 100.0

sum = 708.5

num grades = 9

low grade = 10.0

high grade = 100.0

Comment: What error it throws?

Comment: Please post the error that you get.  If it's an exception, post the stack trace.  If you catch an exception, modify the code to print the stack trace (exception.printStackTrace())

Comment: You need to post only the relevant portion of code, and don't link to external files, people may won't get time to go through all of your code, there will be chances that people may skip your question.

Comment: That's actually the reason that I put them on PasteBin, so it wouldn't take a ton of space on my question

Comment: @tech_geek23, see my answer. Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: I was having an issue of where I put stackTrace, where in the code does it go?

Comment: Naming one of your classes `Class` is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: It wasn't my choice, it's part a lab for a class I'm taking

Comment: I'm not sure it's an issue in `grades.java`, `student.java`, or `class.java`, just look at my edit3 in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with public void `setGrades(String gradeList)` function in Grades `Line 27`
This means that the entire `gradeList` is something like "a b c". Convert this to array function and read individual String. [a],[b],[c]. Use `split` function of String to form an array and populate your `grades[i]`

This method in Scanner is causing the issue which means there is no input left to parse after `scan.nextInt()`;

```
 // If we are at the end of input then NoSuchElement;
  903     // If there is still input left then InputMismatch
  904     private void throwFor() {
  905         skipped = false;
  906         if ((sourceClosed) && (position == buf.limit()))
  907             throw new NoSuchElementException();
  908         else
  909             throw new InputMismatchException();
  910     }
```

Comment: so why would grades, students, and classes, all work appropriately in their runner files but when it comes to referencing to class.java, which would ultimately reference all the others, do I get errors?